# Error only with php 7.1 how to solve the "Too few arguments to function get_query_var()"

Tags: php, wordpress, runtime-error

Please just le me say some things important

1) I'm a completely newbie to php coding, basically i don't know how to code, I'm able just to "understand" something looking at the code but in the most times I don't know how to solve an issue, I just try to change something in the code and try an try again.

2) I see there are other question-topic like this but no one of them seems to solve my issue because no one of them explains WHAT to change in the code.

I have a wordpress site and since my hosting provider updated to php 7.1 I receive this error during a checkout process

```
  Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function get_query_var(), 0 passed in /homepages/27/d717103608/htdocs/clickandbuilds/IlCrudoeIlCotto/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce_events/classes/woohelper.php on line 688 and at least 1 expected in /homepages/27/d717103608/htdocs/clickandbuilds/IlCrudoeIlCotto/wp-includes/query.php:26 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/27/d717103608/htdocs/clickandbuilds/IlCrudoeIlCotto/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce_events/classes/woohelper.php(688): get_query_var() #1 /homepages/27/d717103608/htdocs/clickandbuilds/IlCrudoeIlCotto/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): Woo_Helper->display_thank_you_text('Grazie. Il tuo ...') #2 /homepages/27/d717103608/htdocs/clickandbuilds/IlCrudoeIlCotto/wp-includes/plugin.php(203): WP_Hook->apply_filters('Grazie. Il tuo ...', Array) #3 /homepages/27/d717103608/htdocs/clickandbuilds/IlCrudoeIlCotto/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php(41): apply_filters('woocommerce_tha...', 'Grazie. Il tuo ...', Object(WC_Order)) #4 /homep in /homepages/27/d717103608/htdocs/clickandbuilds/IlCrudoeIlCotto/wp-includes/query.php on line 26
```

I know this is a well-know issue because in php 7.1 what was a "warning" has been promoted to be fatal error
see this:
https://www.bestwebframeworks.com/tutorials/php/153/solve-php-uncaught-argumentcounterror-too-few-arguments-to-function/

and this
http://php.net/manual/en/class.argumentcounterror.php

The problem is.. I completely don't know what to change in my php files to have this working again, and I dont know where to check for some error. 
I understood that this problem belongs to a function that expect like 1 argument and receives nothing, but I dont know how to chek... This place is my last resource.

Then I put here my php files involved in the error, hope that someone will be so kind to help me. Thanks

At these URLs you can find the whole php files
woohelper.php
https://pastebin.com/EAwjg9Wm

class-wp-hook.php
https://pastebin.com/9K9nrk20

query.php
https://pastebin.com/Qy6aGmcX

plugin.php
https://pastebin.com/HutKXEuy

thankyou.php
https://pastebin.com/yDw8mCi8

From here I will just copy the parts that are listed in the error received.

Please also note.. if I revert my server php version prior to 7.1 (e.g. 7.0 or 6.9) everything works fine.

woohelper.php (error in line 688)

```
  public function display_thank_you_text($thankYouText) {

        global $woocommerce;
        global $post;

        $paged = get_query_var();    /*THIS IS LINE 688*/

        $actualLink = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
        $segments = array_reverse(explode('/', $actualLink));

        $orderID = $segments[1];
        $order = new WC_Order($orderID);
        $items = $order->get_items();

        $products = array();

        foreach($items as $item) {

            $products[$item['product_id']] = $item['product_id'];

        }

        foreach($products as $key => $productID) {

            $WooCommerceEventsThankYouText = get_post_meta($productID, 'WooCommerceEventsThankYouText', true);

            if(!empty($WooCommerceEventsThankYouText)) {

                echo $WooCommerceEventsThankYouText."<br/><br/>";

            }

        }

        return $thankYouText;

    }
```

query.php  (error in line 26)

```
    function get_query_var( $var, $default = '' ) {    /* THIS IS LINE 26 */
    global $wp_query;
    return $wp_query->get( $var, $default );
}
```

wp-class-hook.php (error in line 288)

```
        /**
     * Calls the callback functions added to a filter hook.
     *
     * @since 4.7.0
     *
     * @param mixed $value The value to filter.
     * @param array $args  Arguments to pass to callbacks.
     * @return mixed The filtered value after all hooked functions are applied to it.
     */
    public function apply_filters( $value, $args ) {
        if ( ! $this->callbacks ) {
            return $value;
        }

        $nesting_level = $this->nesting_level++;

        $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] = array_keys( $this->callbacks );
        $num_args = count( $args );

        do {
            $this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ] = $priority = current( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] );

            foreach ( $this->callbacks[ $priority ] as $the_ ) {
                if( ! $this->doing_action ) {
                    $args[ 0 ] = $value;
                }

                // Avoid the array_slice if possible.
                if ( $the_['accepted_args'] == 0 ) {
                    $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array() );
                } elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
                    $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
                } else {
/** THIS IS LINE 288 */ $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int)$the_['accepted_args'] ) );
                }
            }
        } while ( false !== next( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] ) );

        unset( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] );
        unset( $this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ] );

        $this->nesting_level--;

        return $value;
    }
```

plugin.php (error in line 203)

```
    function apply_filters( $tag, $value ) {
    global $wp_filter, $wp_current_filter;

    $args = array();

    // Do 'all' actions first.
    if ( isset($wp_filter['all']) ) {
        $wp_current_filter[] = $tag;
        $args = func_get_args();
        _wp_call_all_hook($args);
    }

    if ( !isset($wp_filter[$tag]) ) {
        if ( isset($wp_filter['all']) )
            array_pop($wp_current_filter);
        return $value;
    }

    if ( !isset($wp_filter['all']) )
        $wp_current_filter[] = $tag;

    if ( empty($args) )
        $args = func_get_args();

    // don't pass the tag name to WP_Hook
    array_shift( $args );

/* THIS IS LINE 203 */  $filtered = $wp_filter[ $tag ]->apply_filters( $value, $args );

    array_pop( $wp_current_filter );

    return $filtered;
}
```

thankyou.php

```
    <div class="woocommerce-order">

    <?php if ( $order ) : ?>

        <?php if ( $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) : ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--error woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed"><?php _e( 'Unfortunately your order cannot be processed as the originating bank/merchant has declined your transaction. Please attempt your purchase again.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

            <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--error woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed-actions">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_checkout_payment_url() ); ?>" class="button pay"><?php _e( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' ) ?></a>
                <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ); ?>" class="button pay"><?php _e( 'My account', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </p>

        <?php else : ?>

!-- this is line 41 -!  <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), $order ); ?></p>

            <ul class="woocommerce-order-overview woocommerce-thankyou-order-details order_details">

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__order order">
                    <?php _e( 'Order number:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    <strong><?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></strong>
                </li>

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__date date">
                    <?php _e( 'Date:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    <strong><?php echo wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ); ?></strong>
                </li>

                <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && $order->get_user_id() === get_current_user_id() && $order->get_billing_email() ) : ?>
                    <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__email email">
                        <?php _e( 'Email:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                        <strong><?php echo $order->get_billing_email(); ?></strong>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__total total">
                    <?php _e( 'Total:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    <strong><?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); ?></strong>
                </li>

                <?php if ( $order->get_payment_method_title() ) : ?>
                    <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__payment-method method">
                        <?php _e( 'Payment method:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                        <strong><?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_payment_method_title() ); ?></strong>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </ul>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_' . $order->get_payment_method(), $order->get_id() ); ?>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', $order->get_id() ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), null ); ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/) may help. In short, you need to pass in the variable you're trying to retrieve.

Comment: the variable `$paged` is utilised nowhere then you can just comment the code at ligne 688. and after that contact the developer of this plugin to show him the problem. I don't have found a plugin "WooCommerce event" where do you found it ?

Comment: I know that this is happening cause the &paged parameter is not passing. Problem is I don't know how to pass it beacause I barely can read php and understand something....

The "Woocommerce event" is the FooEvents on codecanyon https://codecanyon.net/item/fooevents-for-woocommerce/11753111

For Sure I will send infos to the developer, I didn't before since I was not sure that the issue was in this file.

And just for who dont knows it, the $paged variable is the "Pagination" boolean to say if there is pagination enabled or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/):

> get_query_var( string $var, mixed $default = '' )
>
> *Retrieve variable in the WP_Query class.*
>
> Parameters $var (string) (Required) The variable key to
>   retrieve.

The first parameter in `get_query_var()` is required. On line 688, you're not passing the first **required** parameter.

Judging by your code you're looking for the 'paged' qvar, so try this for line 688 in woohelper.php:

```
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );
```

Comment: thanks.
Since for me php is difficult to understand, I didn't see that between the () there was no parameter.

I think that this is the pagination parameter, as described here in do wp docs [https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination)

so I think I will try with 

`$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );`

I will let you know if this solves the issue.

Comment: OK. Seems that `$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' );`  works perfectly!  Incredible that was so easy.. I'm fighting with this from a week...Thank you so much!